# L1 convergence of convolution of two L1 function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> let $f$,$g$ be $L^1(\mathbb R)$ functions with Lebesgue measure. Define $f_t(x)=\frac {f(x/t)}t$. Prove $f_t*g$ converges to $ag$ in $L^1$ when $t\to0^+$, where $a=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)dx$.

my approach in brief: since $f,g\in L^1$, by Tonelli-Fubini's theorem, we can show $$\int_{\mathbb R}f_t*gdx=\left(\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)dx\right)\int_{\mathbb R}g(y)dy$$
$$\int_{\mathbb R}f_t*gdx=\left(\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)dx\right)\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)dx$$
$$\int_{\mathbb R}\left(f_t*g-\left(\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)dx\right)\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)\right)dx=0$$
Therefore, $$\int_{\mathbb R}|f_t*g(x)-ag(x)|dx=0$$
I am feeling something is wrong with my approach. Do correct me and give me some hints for solving this simple question. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is wrong because you are saying that if the integral of a function has a limit, then this function converges in $L^1$, which is not true. For another approach, see if the result is true when $g$ is the indicator function of an interval.

Comment: @Gribouillis I don't mean that. I have revised my question. Have a look.

Comment: The new version is not better, you are now saying that if the integral of a function converges to 0, this function converges to 0 in $L^1$, but this is still false.

Comment: @Gribouillis can I bother you to show me how to do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

\begin{equation}
q \left(t\right) := \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}\left|{f}_{t} \ast  g \left(x\right)-a g \left(x\right)\right| d x  \leqslant  \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}\left|{f}_{t} \left(y\right)\right| \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}\left|g \left(x-y\right)-g \left(x\right)\right| d x\right) d y := \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}\left|{f}_{t} \left(y\right)\right| {\varphi} \left(y\right) d y\end{equation}

Suppose that $g$ is the indicator function of an interval
$\left[{\alpha} , {\beta}\right]$, then
$ {\varphi} \left(y\right) = 2 \  \text{min} \left(\left|y\right| , {\beta}-{\alpha}\right)$, hence

\begin{equation}q \left(t\right) \leqslant 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f \left(s\right)\right| \text{min} \left(t \left|s\right| , {\beta}-{\alpha}\right) d s\end{equation}

which converges to $0$ by the monotone convergence theorem when
$t \rightarrow  {0}^{+}$.

The general result follows by density of the space of step functions in
$ {L}^{1} \left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.

Comment: the last inequality is a clever step. If I do the last step, I will split the intervals. Actually there is a post more general to my questions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593945/convergence-of-approximations-of-the-identity-in-lp-mathbb-rd