# The set of smooth functions is dense in H

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $$C_c^\infty([a,b],\mathbb{C}):=\{f\in C^\infty([a,b],\mathbb{C}): f^{(k)}(a)=f^{(k)}(b)=0, k=0,1,...\}$$ Then $C_c^\infty([a,b],\mathbb{C})$ is dense in the Hilbert Space.
Can anyone give me some tips in order to prove this theorem? How can one approach this problem?

Comment: I assume your Hilbert space to be $L^2[a.b]$, then [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3018261/22857) is a proof. It works even for $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami my functions are defined in the Complex plane, isn't it a problem? Or one can argument via the isomorphism of \C to \R^2?

Comment: A function $[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ is harder  to deal with than a function $[a,b]\to\mathbb C$. In the proof I mentioned, every single step works with a complex-valued function; no changes needed.